# Why are my D3.js circles not being created and removed as live data is generated?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to build a globe that shows circles based on a live data source. As data is created, geoJSON circles are added to an array and then are sliced cycled through to only show 10 circles at a time. The first 10 get drawn, but no more are added or removed, and I do not understand why.

https://jsfiddle.net/johndierks/vteL3Lpd/

```
var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

var data = [];

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    data.push({
        lat: (Math.random()*45)-22,
        lon:  (Math.random()*45)-22,
        mag : 2,
        id: "id" + Math.round(Math.random()*1000000000).toString(36)
    });
}

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
    .scale(500)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .rotate([0,0])
    .clipAngle(90);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
var g = svg.append("g");
var circle = d3.geo.circle();

d3.json("world-110m.json", function(error, topology) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
        g.selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
                    .geometries)
        .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
});

var draw = function(){

    console.log(data[0].lat);

    var geocircles = svg.selectAll(".event-circle")
        .data(data);

    geocircles.exit().remove();

    geocircles.enter().append("path")
        .datum(function(d) {
             return circle.origin([d.lon, d.lat]).angle(d.mag)();
        })
        .attr("class", "event-circle")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("angle", 1);
};


var interval = setInterval(function(){
    data.push({
        lat: (Math.random()*45)-22,
        lon:  (Math.random()*45)-22,
        mag : 2,
        id: "id" + Math.round(Math.random()*1000000000).toString(36)
    });

    data = data.slice(1);

    draw();
},2000);
```

Comment: You need a key function for `.data()`, for example `var geocircles = svg.selectAll(".event-circle").data(data, function(d) { return d.id; });`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. If you want to move this to an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `.data()` matches based on the index of the elements. That is, the first datum corresponds to the first DOM element and so on. In particular, this means that if you supply the same number of elements every time, your `enter` and `exit` selections will be empty.

You can modify this by passing a key function to `.data()`:

```
var geocircles = svg.selectAll(".event-circle").data(data, function(d) { return d.id; });
```